# How to wrap and breaking textStreamlit AgGrid's Row?

Tags: ag-grid, streamlit

I need to edit same dataframes when using Streamlit and found this very nice component [AgGrid](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid). However, I'm working with long text and I need to resize the rows to wrap the text in each cell. I need somtheing like `st.table` does:

[image]

How can I get the same type of wrapping AgGrid?
Thanks

Comment: The solution in your edit inserts a line break in the middle of words for me -- are you experiencing that?

Comment: You can avoid breaking in the middle of words by using a custom cellRenderer function

```title_renderer = JsCode("""
    class TitleRenderer {
        init(params) {
            this.eGui.style.whiteSpace = "normal";
            this.eGui.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
        }
        getGui() {
            return this.eGui;
        }
    }
""")```

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add

```
wrapText: true, 
autoHeight: true
```

to the `defaultColdef` property of the grid to do this for all columns,
or to specific column definitions in the `columnDefs` property.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `cellStyle` does it too.

```
gb.configure_column(field="field", header_name="Name", cellStyle={"white-space": 'normal'})
```